# How to make Airbnb's carousel indicators in Blazor

Tags: css, blazor, carousel

I have a carousel where an arbitrary number of images can be shown.

It currently looks like below, where the problem is that the amount carousel indicators quickly gets out of hand.

[image: carousel showcase]

I want to try to do something similar to how Airbnb has it, where it only shows a maximum of 5 dots at any given time. I found an example of an implementation of this [on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/airbnb-carousel-4x9nf?file=/src/index.js), but I'm using Blazor and not React, making it kind of hard to directly translate it.

To show what I'm talking about, their carousel [looks like this](https://i.gyazo.com/a70454e861c33a34da8e6c88fc9de83c.mp4)

My current implementation in Blazor looks like his

```
<span class="progress-dots">
    @for (int i = 0; i < Imgs.Count; i++)
    {
        <span class='progress-dot @( currentImage == i ? "active" : "")'></span>
    }
</span>
```

where `currentImage` is just tracking the index of the active image. This just couples with some simple css to show which one is active.

```
.progress-dots {

    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;

    span.progress-dot {

        width: 0.45rem;
        height: 0.45rem;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background: rgba(174, 174, 174, 0.453);
        margin: 0.2rem 0.15rem;

        &.active {
            background: #FFF;
        }

    }
}
```

Here is a [Blazor repl](https://blazorrepl.telerik.com/cwvabSvO09HNo7u743) with a stripped down version of my own implementation to test how it works.

Comment: You have many functionalities that your codesanbox example has that you did not implement in your Blazor Repl: Make a loop when getting to the list boundaries, be able to click on the dots to display the right image, the animation of the dots moving, display the chosen number of dots, etc... Try to go with one at a time and come back with more specific questions. Or just specify what functionality you aim at adding in this question and what you tried to do.

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine I was not asking about any of that other functionality. Just the part about a limited amount of dots, where the active one is in the center when not at one of the edges of the carousel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to take into account the edge cases. The solution I am giving can probably be improved or cleaner, I just focused on a working example.

```
<div class="img-container">
    <span class="progress-dots">
        @{
            int imgIncMin = 0;
            int imgIncMax = Imgs.Count;
            int dotsDisplayed = DotsDisplayedAround * 2 + 1;
            if(Imgs.Count > dotsDisplayed){
                if(currentImage < DotsDisplayedAround){
                    imgIncMin = 0;
                    imgIncMax = dotsDisplayed;
                }
                else if(currentImage + DotsDisplayedAround >= Imgs.Count){
                    imgIncMin = Imgs.Count - dotsDisplayed;
                    imgIncMax = Imgs.Count;
                }
                else{
                    imgIncMin = currentImage - DotsDisplayedAround;
                    imgIncMax = currentImage + DotsDisplayedAround + 1;
                }
            }
        }
        @for (int i = imgIncMin; i < imgIncMax; i++)
        {
            <span class='progress-dot @( currentImage == i ? "active" : "")'></span>
        }
    </span>
</div>

<div class="btn btn-dark" @onclick='() => { currentImage = currentImage - 1 >= 0 ? currentImage - 1 : Imgs.Count - 1 ; }'>Previous</div>
<div class="btn btn-dark" @onclick='() => { currentImage = (currentImage + 1) % Imgs.Count; }'>Next</div>

@code {
    const int DotsDisplayedAround = 2;
    int currentImage = 0;
    List<string> Imgs = new List<string>() { "", "", "", "", "", "", ""};
}
```

[Blazor repl](https://blazorrepl.telerik.com/GcbuboFy37GRiso812)